# SAML 2.0 using ADAL4j

Tags: azure, saml-2.0, adal, opensaml

Am experimenting SAML 2.0 SSO from a java web application using Azure AD as IDP.

I modified the sample - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect

to generate a SAML request.

But am getting the below error -

AADSTS75005: The request is not a valid Saml2 protocol message

I tried using OpenSAML library to generate SAML Request.

I would like to know if ADAL4J supports SAML 2.0. If yes, can someone share a sample?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I followed this sample to generate SAML request - 
http://www.john-james-andersen.com/blog/programming/sample-saml-2-0-authnrequest-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

ADAL is a wrapper around a protocol.

Currently, that protocol is OpenID Connect / OAuth.

You need a client side [SAML stack](https://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

A lot of Java applications use Spring security.

Answer (score 0):

I think I faced the same or similar problem, and I've found that I am receiving response from custom identity provider in SAML1.1 standard, but ADAL4J recognizes it as SAML2.0 . What I had to do is use modified library, with changed implementation of method isTokenSaml2() in WSTrustResponse class (I've added a lot of additional logging in ADAL4J too). Token type extracted from response was other than expected - "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion"